# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore store images

Tags: ios, icloud

I want to store some images into `iCloud` with `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` but i don't know any possibility, only to save the `NSData` of the image inside a key, but this will generate a notification `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreQuotaViolationChange`.

"The total amount of space available in your app’s key-value store, for a given user, is 1 MB. There is a per-key value size limit of 1 MB, and a maximum of 1024 keys." - Apple Documentation.

Do you know a method for this?

Thanks!

Comment: A method for what? As the docs say, you can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's why I ask if there is another method to save images to iCloud.